# I want to move sd card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, htc-droid-incredible

I want to move a micro SD card from an HTC Aquire into my Galaxy s2 so that I can access the pictures and the music , how do I do that ?

Comment: GSMArena's never heard of a phone called HTC Aquire, nor even Acquire. Could you give some more details about this phone?

Comment: Well you should not use that site to check for phones then! Google confirms it exists! http://pcdphones.com/our-devices/products/172-adr6285om

Comment: I'm not sure what is so complicated about removing a micro SD from one phone and putting it into a another. What is your problem exactly? Can you not find the micro SD card? Can you not get the back off the Acquire? 

Seem like a very simple thing to do - something that doesn't usually require the assistance of the internet!

Comment: Open the back of the Acquire, gently remove the micro SD card. Open the back of the S2 and gently insert the micro SD card... Result!

Comment: It looks like it could be a variant of the HTC Evo 4G based on the specs. Or at least it appers to be very similar to it. http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_evo_design_4g-4202.php

Answer (score 0):

If you go into storage options on your phone under external SD card there should be an option to unmount SD card for safe removal. Select this option and once it is unmounted open the back of the phone eject the SD card, open the back of the Galaxy S2, insert the SD card and you've successfully moved your SD card!